What are notable references in Shikanoko Nokonoko Koshitantan?
Shikanoko Nokonoko Koshitantan, also known as My Deer Friend Nokotan, has a lot of references packed into it.
What are some of the more notable references throughout the show?

This question is a bit too broadly scoped. Instead of asking for everything try to narrow things down to at least an episode.

@кяαzєя Some other questions (like this one) were received well, and are pretty similar.

Again it's the scope. The Eva question does not ask for ALL references, but rather ANY reference. Multiple ppl can contribute answers, but they don't have to cover everything.
